# How to optimize quartz 2d?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, optimization

I have a block of code that's essentially:

```
    for(int i=0;i<aInt;i++){
        CGPoint points[2] = {CGPointMake(i,0),CGPointMake(i,bArray[i])};
        CGContextStrokeLineSegments(myContext, points, 2);
    }
```

which is causing a bit of a bottleneck when aInt gets large, as it's likely to do in my case. I don't know enough about quartz 2d to know how to best optimize this. Is it better to create a single huge point array in the loop and then stoke the entire array once?

Or more ideally, I've just optimized a different part of code dealing with arrays. In doing so, I converted to using C-style arrays which sped things up tremendously. Is there a similar low-level way of doing the above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also imagine making a large array will make it faster. There will definitely be less calls into `CGContextStrokeLineSegments`.

```
CGPoint *points = (CGPoint*)malloc(sizeof(CGPoint)*aInt*2);

for(int i=0;i<aInt;i++){
    points[i*2] = CGPointMake(i,0);
    points[i*2+1] = CGPointMake(i,bArray[i]));
}

CGContextStrokeLineSegments(myContext, points, aInt*2);

free(points);
```

Comment: Thanks. Using something similar to this code cut the time of the loop by 75%. I'd still like it faster, but this is a big improvement, so I'll take it for now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, creating a single large array will definitely be faster than stroking each individual line segment.